# Pass value Pager Fragment

Tags: java, android

I had a problem with passing the value to my class:

```
public class FragmentViewPager extends Fragment {

    public static int p;
    private FragmentPagerItemAdapter adapter;
    private static final String TAG = "log";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_pager, container, false);

        adapter = new FragmentPagerItemAdapter(
                    getChildFragmentManager(), FragmentPagerItems.with(getActivity())
                    .add("1", AnimalsFragment.class)
                    .add("2", AnimalsFragment.class)
                    .add("3", AnimalsFragment.class)
                    .add("4", AnimalsFragment.class)
                    .add("5", AnimalsFragment.class)
                    .create());

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        SmartTabLayout viewPagerTab = (SmartTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpagertab);
        viewPagerTab.setViewPager(viewPager);

        // определяем позицию фрагмента
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                p = position;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

I get the value:

```
public class AnimalsFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
...
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_animals, container, false);

        // получаем позицию фрагмента
        position = FragmentViewPager.p;
        Log.i(TAG, "position = " + position);
...
```

Logs:

```
I/log: position = 1
I/log: position = 2
I/log: position = 3
```

There are 5 fragments, the first '0' and last '4' are not displayed.
But if you place logs in the method onPageSelected() logs are displayed correctly.
How to correctly convey the values of paging in a class?

Comment: Please post your code including PagerAdapter

Comment: Added full code

Answer (score 1):

`ViewPager` creates current, previous and next fragments which you can set and change the number with ViewPager's `setOffscreenPageLimit` method. (The default is 1. You cannot set it to 0.)

So when you put your Log code in `onCreateView`, 3 of your `Fragments` will be created and you'll see the log three times and your p variable will be last created fragment's position since your default screen limit is 1.

And when you put your Log code in `onPageSelected` your log only'll work when you swipe the `ViewPager`.

Here you can check for more detail:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Comment: But if you place logs in the method onPageSelected() logs are displayed correctly.